# Impossible to update Entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

Under Symfony 2 (last version), I'm trying to update my entity :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:upate --force
```

I got this error message into my terminal :

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>     Unrecognized options "0, 1, 2, 3" under "security.firewalls.access_control"

I'm new in Symfony, and I don't know where I can search to resolve this problem.

This is the security.yml file :

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
```

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    #main:
        #anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false


access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is not related to you trying to update your entity but pointing to an issue with the `security.yml` configuration file. In this case, the indentation of your `access_control` section is incorrect and should be at the same indent level as the `firewalls` keywords. YAML files are indent sensitive so this should sort your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to indent access_control section at the same level with firewalls